# Change of variables proof on triangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ and let $R$ be the triangular region with vertices $(0,0) (1,0),$ and $(0,1)$. Show that $\iint_R f(x+y)\,dA = \int_0^1uf(u)\,du$

I've found $u=x+y$ and $v=y-x$.

when I calculate the Jacobian a $2$ appears and it seems a little bit false.

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1f(u)2\,\,dvdu$$

A little clue will be appreciated 
[image: this is the triangle that i tweaked somewhat to get v]

[image: The area in the uv plane]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistake $1$ is to multiply by $2$, in fact it should be divides by $2$.

Mistake $2$ is assuming that the corresponding $(u,v)$-region is going to be a square, it is actually a triangle.

If you fix the $u=0$, $v$ is going to take value from $0$ to $0$.

If you fix $u=1$, $v$ is going to take value from $-1$ to $1$.

If $u=u_0$, $v$ takes value from $-u_0$ to $u_0$.

Hence after transforming the coordinate, the right region is

$$\int_0^1\int_{-u}^u \frac12f(u)\,dv\,du$$

Comment: How do you know that you have to fix u to 0 ?  is the first triangle given by the question in the uv plane ?

Comment: how do you know where is the first triangle, i mean from his coordinates i assumed that it is in a xy plane because that’s the only way i could find a equation like x+y=1, i tried to do it by assuming that it is a triangle but it didn’t work that’s why i manufactured this fake square to have a function v

Comment: Oh, that is just to illustrate what are the value that $v$ take when $u$ is fixed. Your first picture is correct. After transforming, the triangle region connects the points $(0,0), (1,1)$, and $(1,-1)$ in the $(u,v)$-coordinate system.

Comment: I feel like you just had that intuition to tilt the graph clockwise. but I cannot find a way to help myself, i had that intuition but i cannot prove it. Also how do you get those coordinates ? why do you hold u constant while changing v? I cannot think of any reason to do that. what is your u and your v? are you using the same as me ? sorry about all these questions it’s just a little confusing.

Comment: I am using your coordinate system. Your transformation is just rotation and scaling.  Try to see where are your vertices being mapped to. For example $(0,1)$ in your $(x,y)$ coordinate gets map to $(0+1,1-0)=(1,1)$ in your $(u,v)$ coordinate system.

Comment: it’s all make sense now, all i’m doing is remapping, do you have some exercises like that? this is the most difficult in my book on this chapter. thank you !

Comment: unfortunatley, nope, i don't have some exercises like that.